# Physical memory in task manager don't changes when momory is allocated

Tags: memory, taskmanager

all
  My program maybe have a memory issue, so I try to find information about memory usage provided by various tools. In order to find the cause, I do simple experiments as well.
In release mode, I add the following code,

```
pChar = new char[((1<<30)/2)];
for(int i; i < ((1<<30)/2); i++)
{
    pChar[i] = i % 256;
}
```

When the code is executed, the available physical memory in Windows task manager doesn't change. In my view, the compiler may remove the code to boost performance. I declare the variable as one global variable. It doesn't work. But in debug mode, the available physical memory in Windows task manager changes as expected.  I can't understand that.

I have another question. Will the new operation allocate memory from virtual memory if the physical memory runs out. Or one exception will be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed quite possible that the compiler detects a "write-only" variable. Since it's non-`volatile`, the writes can be safely eliminated, and then there's no need for the OS to actually allocate RAM.

`new` just allocates address space, on modern systems. Physical RAM is allocated when needed. Typically this happens when the ctor runs, as it initializes the members. But in `new char` there's of course no ctor.

Comment: Thanks. Will the program run slow if the memory is allocated on virtual memory? Is the decision made by the compiler or OS?

Comment: All allocations are against virtual memory, so the "slow if on virtual memory" question does not make sense, and there's no decision to be made. RAM is assigned later, by the OS, and only as needed, not on allocation.